# Cannot borrow value as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable

Tags: rust

I am having the following error that I don't know why I couldn't make reproducible at all, so sorry for that.

[image]

If I uncomment the `let v` line and replace `value.as_slice().to_vec()` by `v` it works, but then I would have done an unecessary `Vec` allocation. What would be the workaround in this case?

Full reproducible code below:

```
use arrow2::{array::PrimitiveArray, types::NativeType};
use ndarray::{Array2, ArrayView2, ArrayViewMut2};
use num_traits::Float;

enum Array2Enum<'a, T> {
    Mut(ArrayViewMut2<'a, T>),
    View(ArrayView2<'a, T>),
    Owned(Array2<T>),
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Clone)]
pub struct HFloatArray<T: NativeType + Float> {
    pub inner: PrimitiveArray<T>,
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Clone)]
pub struct HFloatMatrix<T: NativeType + Float> {
    pub inner: HFloatArray<T>,
    pub ncols: usize,
}

impl<T> HFloatArray<T>
where
    T: NativeType + Float,
{
    /// Returns the length of this HArray.
    pub fn len(&self) -> usize {
        self.inner.len()
    }

    /// Gets the underlying slice.
    pub fn as_slice(&self) -> &[T] {
        self.inner.values().as_slice()
    }

    /// Returns an option of a mutable reference to the values.
    pub fn get_mut_values(&mut self) -> Option<&mut [T]> {
        self.inner.get_mut_values()
    }
}

impl<T: NativeType + Float> HFloatMatrix<T> {
    /// Number of elements.
    pub fn len(&self) -> usize {
        self.inner.len()
    }

    /// Number of columns.
    pub fn ncols(&self) -> usize {
        self.ncols
    }

    /// Number of rows.
    pub fn nrows(&self) -> usize {
        self.len() / self.ncols
    }

    /// Gets the underlying slice.
    pub fn as_slice(&self) -> &[T] {
        self.inner.inner.values().as_slice()
    }

    /// Returns an option of a mutable reference to the values
    pub fn get_mut_values(&mut self) -> Option<&mut [T]> {
        self.inner.get_mut_values()
    }
}

impl<'a, T> From<&'a mut HFloatMatrix<T>> for Array2Enum<'a, T>
where
    T: Float + NativeType,
{
    fn from(value: &'a mut HFloatMatrix<T>) -> Array2Enum<'a, T> {
        let nrows = value.nrows();
        let ncols = value.ncols();

        //let v = value.clone().as_slice().to_vec();

        if let Some(slice) = value.get_mut_values() {
            Array2Enum::Mut(
                // Ok to unwrap.
                ArrayViewMut2::from_shape((ncols, nrows), slice).unwrap(),
            )
        } else {
            // Ok to unwrap.
            let arr = Array2::from_shape_vec((ncols, nrows), value.as_slice().to_vec()).unwrap();
            Array2Enum::Owned(arr)
        }
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

Comment: Please post your actual code instead that of screenshot.

Comment: just did, sorry for that.

Comment: Please post all the code **and** errors as text (see [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) as for why). Also, show the errors that the compilers gives you, instead of what your IDE shows you, because the compiler gives self-contained errors.

Comment: Made a minimal example https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9a0feeacac2a2f082450780b7640ffa8

Comment: It also looks like cloning `value` will make the first branch always fail anyway, so that's not ideal.

Comment: wouldn't the clone be dropped before that? Since I don't bind the clone to any variable...

Comment: Yeah I guess so. The [documentation](https://docs.rs/arrow2/latest/arrow2/buffer/struct.Buffer.html#method.get_mut_slice) says it'll return Some if it "has not been cloned" but that seems to be incorrect.

Comment: The closest I could get without calling `get_mut_values` twice is `Arc::make_mut`, but arrow2 doesn't have that function, and it returns `&mut T` in both cases instead of `&mut T` or `T`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that temporaries live until the end of the statement, so the temporary created by `value.get_mut_values()` (which implies a mutable borrow on `value`) lives until the end of the entire if let/else statement, not just for the scope of the `if let` branch, and thus it maintains a mutable borrow on the `value` for that extent.

Essentially, it translates to this:

```rust
    {
        let mut_value = value.get_mut_values();
        if let Some(slice) = mut_value {
            Array2Enum::Mut(
                // Ok to unwrap.
                ArrayViewMut2::from_shape((ncols, nrows), slice).unwrap(),
            )
        } else {
            // Ok to unwrap.
            let arr = Array2::from_shape_vec((ncols, nrows), value.as_slice().to_vec()).unwrap();
            Array2Enum::Owned(arr)
        }
    }
```

which makes the scoping (and thus the problem) clearer: `mut_value` overlaps with the second branch.

One option is to just avoid the upfront borrow:

```rust
        if value.get_mut_values().is_some() {
            Array2Enum::Mut(
                ArrayViewMut2::from_shape((ncols, nrows), value.get_mut_values().unwrap()).unwrap(),
            )
        } else {
            let arr = Array2::from_shape_vec((ncols, nrows), value.as_slice().to_vec()).unwrap();
            Array2Enum::Owned(arr)
        }
```

although how nice it is depends on how expensive `get_mut_values` is.

Comment: The issue isn't that it lives to the end of the statement. You can tell by explicitly returning in the `if let` block and then unwrapping the `else` block. That will still not work.

Comment: @drewtato that just proves that's the issue, the `if let` statement doesn't end until the `}` of the `else` block, which is precisely how long the borrow is held. It is a known limitation solved by polonius if it ever goes stable I think.

Comment: Could you explain why this worked? Does `is_some()` do something different here?

Comment: And do you have any unsafe workaround for that? Without needing to call `get_mut_values` multiple times?

Comment: @cafce25 I mean removing the else block. Like this https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9a0feeacac2a2f082450780b7640ffa8